# Problem installing mysqlclient for a website hosted on namecheap shared hosting plan

Tags: python, django

I have my small Django website hosted on namecheap. I want to migrate from sqlite3 database to MySQL but when I try to run the `pip install mysqlclient` command, I get the following error:

```
(majestylink:3.7)[majeaozd@server255 majestylink]$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:   command: /home/majeaozd/virtualenv/majestylink/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hitubcqu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hitubcqu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-7na75mzf       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-hitubcqu/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (30 lines):
  /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/majeaozd/virtualenv/majestylink/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hitubcqu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hitubcqu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'install --record /tmp/pip-record-n7wkk7_3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/majeaozd/virtualenv/majestylink/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-hitubcqu/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
(majestylink:3.7)[majeaozd@server255 majestylink]$ [majeaozd@server255 ~]$ source /home/majeaozd/virtualenv/majestylink/3.7/bin/activate &
& cd /home/majeaozd/majestylink
(majestylink:3.7)[majeaozd@server255 majestylink]$ pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/majeaozd/virtualenv/majestylink/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/p
ip-install-suuh39r6/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-suuh39r6/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-jx51xrst       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-suuh39r6/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (30 lines):
  /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel  running build  running build_py  creating build  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/majeaozd/virtualenv/majestylink/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-suuh39r6/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-suuh39r6/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'install --record /tmp/pip-record-xprbswhp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/majeaozd/virtualenv/majestylink/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-suuh39r6/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
(majestylink:3.7)[majeaozd@server255 majestylink]$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/majeaozd/virtualenv/majestylink/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/p
ip-install-gf11y7_0/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gf11y7_0/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'
open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bd
ist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-qmtjdtbq
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gf11y7_0/mysqlclient/  Complete output (30 lines):  /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/majeaozd/virtualenv/majestylink/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gf11y7_0/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gf11y7_0/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'install --record /tmp/pip-record-_spsvark/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/majeaozd/virtualenv/majestylink/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gf11y7_0/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/majeaozd/virtualenv/majestylink/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools,tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gf11y7_0/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gf11y7_0/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_spsvark/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/majeaozd/virtualenv/majestylink/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
(majestylink:3.7)[majeaozd@server255 majestylink]$
```

I have tried most of the answers I found online but to no avail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 in namecheap, the problem is on shared hosting, because the root acces is limited.

You need to contact support, they will temporary enable compiler for your account so that you will be able install it.

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9832/29/how-to-run-python-scripts-and-configure-virtual-environment/

Answer (score 3):

That's a permission denied error, which probably means you dont have the permission to install python packages globally. What I would recommend is creating a virtual environment

```
# install virtualenv for the user
python3 -m pip install virtualenv --user

# initialize a new virtual environment and name it "venv"
python3 -m virtualenv venv 

# activate the virtual environment
source venv/bin/activate

# once the environment is activated you'll see the name of the environment 
# before the shell prompt. 

# now you can install your dependencies.
(venv)$:- pip install mysqlclient
```

if you don't want to create the virtual environment you can install the package using

`pip install mysqlclient --user`

Comment: I already have a virtual environment. I skipped it earlier but I've updated the code to contain the activated virtual environment. I have activated virtual env but the command is not working

Comment: Using the `--user` flag, I get the following error saying `ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.`

Comment: Maybe my answer wasn't clear enough. You can use the `--user` flag when you're not using a virtual environment. When you have activated one, simply do `pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: It still didn't install. And my website is now saying `It works!

Python 3.6.8`

Comment: congratulations! if my answer helped mind marking it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not sound like an answer, but it worked for me on several occasions.

Just roll down the version of the packages. I usually encounter the `permission denied` error with packages like `pillow` and `numpy`.

Just remove them from your `requirements.txt` file and install them individually but with a lower version.

For example:

```
pip install numpy==1.19.5
```

this above installation worked for me while I got permission denied error on `pip install numpy==1.23.4`